Powerapps - Cannot capture error on SearchUser function
I am building an app to populate a particular user data using the SearchUser function once the user clicks a button, but it throws an error if the search terms contain "&".
I want to use IfError to capture this error without success, it will still display the same system error on the top. Does anyone know how to fix it?
Thanks in advance.
Button (OnSelect):
IfError(
    UpdateContext({var1:First(Office365Users.SearchUser({searchTerm: "ABC-MKT & BD"})).Surname}),
    Set(varErr,1);
    Notify(
        "An error occurred: ",
        NotificationType.Error
    )
)


Consider using escape characters within strings

The result of UpdateContext in the expression below isn't an error - even if the result of Office365Users.SearchUser returns an error, it will assign the error to var1 - and this assignment works as expected.
IfError(
  UpdateContext({
    var1: First(Office365Users.SearchUser({ searchTerm: "ABC-MKT & BD" })).Surname
  }),
  Set(varErr,1); Notify( "An error occurred: ", NotificationType.Error )
)

You can update it to something similar to the following, which will check the value of the variable (which would have the error):
UpdateContext({
  var1: First(Office365Users.SearchUser({ searchTerm: "ABC-MKT & BD" })).Surname
});
IfError(var1, Set(varErr, 1); Notify( "An error occurred: ", NotificationType.Error ))

or
UpdateContext({
  var1: First(Office365Users.SearchUser({ searchTerm: "ABC-MKT & BD" })).Surname
});
If(
  IsError(var1),
  Set(varErr, 1); Notify( "An error occurred: ", NotificationType.Error )
)


Nyc insight, I never thought of that.
